# How to get option value $OPTARG correctly?

Tags: bash, shell-script, options

I would like to get an option value when launching a shcell. I wrote:

```
optstring=hcnxl:
V=0
 
while getopts $optstring opt; do
  case $opt in
    h) V=1 ;;
    c) V=2 ;;
    n) V=3 ;;
    x) V=4 ;;
    l) V=$OPTARG ;;
    *) echo -e "wrong synthax" && exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
echo :: ${OPTARG} : $OPTARG
```

But when I run the script with `-l <n>` the option is always empty.

What am I getting wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `OPTARG` is only valid on the iteration where `getopts` set `opt` to `l` (or any option that takes an arg). It doesn't make sense to use it outside the loop. After all, what should happen if you run `myscript -l 123 -l 456`? Of if you just run `myscript -h`?

Comment: I don't get it: so where does option `l` go? isn't it inside the `while` loop?

Comment: inside the loop, you're copying `$OPTARG` to `V`, yes. Outside the loop you're printing `$OPTARG` again (which is going to be reset by then), not `$V` (which would have the value you assigned to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
echo "$V"
```

You don't need to `shift` anything, `while getopts` already loops over the options.

Comment: They do need to `shift` if they later want to process the non-option arguments.

Comment: Actually, it did not work: V always gets the default value of 0 even if I set `l) V="$OPTARG" ;;`...echo "$V"

Comment: It works for me, e.g. `script.sh -x -l 9` returns `9`; `script.sh -x -n` returns `3`. Try running it with `set -xv` to see how bash evaluates each line.

Comment: Yes, now it is working. Thanks